# Open Graph action with two people

Tags: facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta, multiple-users

I have been looking through to Open Graph documentation and I haven't come across actions that can be defined for multiple users.

For instance, x ran a route with y, or x sent y a photo.

Is it currently possible to do this and if not, does anyone know if there are plans to allow this in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I have found for "x sent y a photo" is to define an object photo on facebook with additional property whose name is "To" and type is "Profile".

Answer (score 2):

Just use the arg. ....&tags[]=USERID1&tags[]=USERID2... While publishing the action.